# Sort table columns with angularjs in non-angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

Ok, suppose I have a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td><td>2222222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mark</td><td>3333333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alice</td><td>1999999</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That was rendered by non-angularjs app.
All the examples I see on the web suggest that I have a controller and a scope and all the angularjs stuff, but what if I want to deal with existing data?

One time I have this headache I've surrendered and re-wrote everything to be an angularjs app.
There is a major issue with: **it's not indexed** by the search engines. Or at least not by all of them (I know google is super-smart, but that's only google).

What if I want to use angularjs power and have this existing data? How do I bind those values of the table and make it sortable?

Comment: The best way I can think of would be to create a directive that takes the table, parses the data out of (probably using jquery for sanity's sake), and then rerenders it out using a proper angular template. Ugly as all hell, for sure.

Comment: Yes, I had a hope there is another way :)

Comment: I suppose, alternatively, the directive could be an interface around something like http://trentrichardson.com/2013/12/16/sort-dom-elements-jquery/ . It's not really angular doing any heavy lifting for the sort, but the directive could be used to map scope values to various comparators, using $watch.

Comment: If you re in a non-angular application, is seems weird to me that you still use it. There is so many small library light and efficient to perform such task like underscoreJS. You still need to keep in mind your MVC (if you care) and perform this sort on a model level, not in your view. So my question is : is it really mandatory for you to use angular for such thing ? :D

Comment: No, it's not, I'm actually going to use React and pre-compile JSXs :)

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting and I think it is useful when we want to give old web application power of angularjs.

The following code is nothing more than my idea without careful consideration.

In Html

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href ng-click="mgrtable.sort('name')">Name</href></td><td><a href ng-click="mgrtable.sort('phone')">Phone</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-init="mgrtable.add_row('John', '2222222')">
            <td>{{mgrtable.rows[0].name}}</td><td>{{mgrtable.rows[0].phone}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-init="mgrtable.add_row('Mark', '3333333')">
            <td>{{mgrtable.rows[1].name}}</td><td>{{mgrtable.rows[1].phone}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-init="mgrtable.add_row('Alice', '1999999')">
            <td>{{mgrtable.rows[2].name}}</td><td>{{mgrtable.rows[2].phone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In javascript

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .factory('ManagerTable', function(){
        return function(){
            this.rows = [];
            var desc = {
                name: true, phone: true
            }
            this.add_row = function(name, phone){
                this.rows.push({name: name, phone: phone});
            }
            this.sort = function(key){
                var _desc = desc[key];
                desc[key] = !_desc;
                this.rows.sort(function(a, b){
                    var vala = a[key],
                        valb = b[key];
                    if (_desc){
                        return vala > valb ? 1: -1;
                    }else{
                        return vala > valb ? -1: 1;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    })
;

function myctrl($scope, ManagerTable){
    $scope.mgrtable = new ManagerTable();
}
```

[Demo jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/fh7qcdff/1/)

When you want to add some feature about the table data, all you have to do is adding the function of `ManagerTable`. Although I know html is not clean, I think this way could keep the MVC principle and angular-way.

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: How does this solve the problem that the table won't be indexed by web crawlers?

Comment: Oops! honestly I forgot about the problem of search engine. However the data(lets say 'John') still exists on HTML therefore I hope search engine might crawl. 
If the data needs to exist inside `td` tag for search engine, unfortunately we need to put the data with `display:none`.